# Testing before_save with RSpec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using a before_save call to update all the records that belong to a particular master.  Both have a field called item_id:

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
  before_save :update_records
  def update_records
    self.records.find_each do |r|
      r.item_id = self.item_id
      r.save
    end
  end
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This works as intended (leaving aside for the minute whether it's a good idea to do something like this).  However I can't get an RSpec test that passes.  This is what I tried:

```
describe Master do
  describe 'before_save' do
    it 'updates records belonging to it' do
      master = FactoryGirl.create(:master, item_id: 1)
      record = FactoryGirl.create(:record, master_id: master.id, item_id: 1)
      master.item_id = 2
      master.save
      record.item_id.should == 2
    end
  end
end
```

The reason is interesting.  The model does its work on a second instance of a Record model which gets saved successfully, but is not returned to the spec:

```
"MASTER - CREATED IN SPEC"
#<Master:0x007fd0ed55ec20> {
    :id => 26,
    :item_id => 1,
}
"RECORD - CREATED IN SPEC"
#<Record:0x007fd0ea157e40> {
    :id => 16,
    :item_id => 1,
    :master_id => 26,
}
"RECORD - AFTER SAVE IN MODEL"
#<Record:0x007fd0ed2f9a70> {
    :id => 16,
    :item_id => 2,
    :master_id => 26,
}
"MASTER - UPDATED IN SPEC"
#<Master:0x007fd0ed55ec20> {
    :id => 26,
    :item_id => 2,
}
"RECORD - FINAL IN SPEC"
#<Record:0x007fd0ea157e40> {
    :id => 16,
    :item_id => 1,
    :master_id => 26,
}
```

Do you know:

- why this is happening?
- How I can get this spec to pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your record is just showing you old data, and needs to be refreshed. Try:

```
record.reload.item_id.should == 2
```